# sync custom entities using force.com ide?

Tags: eclipse, apex-code, visualforce, force.com

right now we are using svn to share code for our force.com/visualforce project. It works great controllers, components, pages and static resources.

The problem is it seems the salesforce.schema file is not really a local file, its a placeholder that checks your server and tells you your current schema.

We want to baseline our schema changes/updates to a file so we can share in svn.

I found this:
http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/Custom-Objects-in-Force-com-IDE/td-p/445363

But we cant seem to figure out what do do/how to get it to work.

So in a nutshell, we are looking for a way for Developer A to create a custom schema object in their own SF Sandbox, somehow get this info into a file in svn (ideally through the force.com ide), then check it in so developer B can check it out and apply it to their server. (the same way we do for code).

Any help would be great!

thanks
Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, we finally figured this out through trial and error:

To make this work:

- right click on project, click "Force.com/Add Remove Metadata Components"
- go down to custom ojbjects, open that up, make sure all your custom objects are checked, click apply, then say "NO" to dialog
- then right click on src and click "Force.com/Syncronize with Server, find your objects, and click "Apply Server to Project"
- now your files will be local, check them into SVN and you are golden.